# Same font, font-weight, and browser, different websites, but giving different results

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am making a website and wanting to have the same look for the same font from the other website. However, they give different results when I set their font-weight to 600.

The font is Proxima Nova Regular.

The following is what they look like:

font-weight: normal

color: #98a9af

My website

[image]

The other website

[image]

font-weight: 600

color: #98a9af

My website

[image]

The other website

[image]

Perhaps to some they look similar, but my website is bolder.

Thank you.

Andy

Comment: Try to make a [mcve]. First create a simple test page only with this text and rules inside, let's call it "witness". Then check which of their or your page exposes the same behavior as this "witness". Take the source of the other and start removing everything unrelated, until it exposes the same behavior. You'll find what causes this issue. If from there you are still not able to figure out how to fix it, then come back here and let us know.

Comment: How do I include downloaded font in Stack Snippets?

Comment: Is there a place in stack overflow that I can upload the file, and then refer to it using @font-face?

Comment: You could *maybe* encode it to a dataURI, Though you might reach the max-limit of chars rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem. I found out that my website didn't have the font face of medium bold which is 600 for font-weight. So, when the browser didn't find the font face, it tried to mimic, but then the result was not as good.

Answer (score -2):

you can use something like Normalize css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
it will make browsers render all elements more consistently.because each browser has its own user agent stylesheet and it might be a bit different according to there own style guides.